# What all are the types of java files src/main/java and src/test/java contains in a maven project?

Tags: maven, selenium, webdriver

What are all of the java files contained in different folders of `src/main/java` and `src/test/java`? What is their usage in details?

[image: Maven project structure.[1]]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answers to this question are available in the Apache Maven product documentation and it is not difficult to find.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard [Maven Java project structure](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), those two folders basicly involves:

> **src/main/java**
>
> Inside this folder you can put **all the application source files**. Classes and packages for the main (real) artifact should be put in this folder. If the artifact is a jar file, all the classes and packages will be in the root folder of the generated jar, so it will be available by default on the runtime classpath.
>
> **src/test/java**
>
> Inside this folder you can put **all the application test source files**. Classes and packages for the test artifact should be put in this folder. All the content inside of this directory will NOT be put in the classpath of the generated artifact.

(Based on: [Maven Project Structure Example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/maven/maven-project-structure-example/))

---

The basic use of exisitng API is throughly documented within Selenium API Documentation, for example related [Interface DriverFactory](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/). I would assume that the initial project classes are some boilerplate code for making your testing process easier and more effective.